# Adding javascript function affect in flask app

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am getting text and some important words list from python script which I am displaying using flask in UI.

I wanted to highlight important keywords in text. Which works fine when I test it on w3scool compiler.

[image]

```
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<div id="vow_p"></div>
<script>
var vow = "Night gathers, and now my watch begins. It shall not end until my death. I shall take no wife, hold no lands, father no children. I shall wear no crowns and win no glory. I shall live and die at my post. I am the sword in the darkness. I am the watcher on the walls. I am the shield that guards the realms of men. I pledge my life and honor to the Night's Watch, for this night and all the nights to come.";

var wordsToBold=["night","watcher"];

function makeBold(input, wordsToBold) {
   return input.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)(' + wordsToBold.join('|') + ')(\\b)','ig'), '$1<u><b>$2</u></b>$3');
}

document.getElementById("vow_p").innerHTML = makeBold(vow, wordsToBold);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Same code I have integrated in my flask app. Here problem is only one, first keyword getting highlighted rest keywords does not get any effect. Am I making any mistake?

app.py

app = Flask(**name**)

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('text-process.html')
```

in text-process.html

```
<script>
// var vow = {{ item }};
var someJavaScriptVar = '{{ wordres }}';
var wordsToBold =['reduced'];


function makeBold(input, wordsToBold) {
    return input.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)(' + wordsToBold.join(',') + ')(\\b)','ig'), '$1<mark>$2</mark>$3');
}

document.getElementById("vow_p").innerHTML = makeBold(someJavaScriptVar, wordsToBold);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
wordsToBold.join(',')
```

to

```
wordsToBold.join('|')
```

The `|` in a regexp means »or« so `/one|word|of|those/` matches: one OR word OR …

`/one,word,of,those/` as created by your script matches the whole string.

Additionally

```
var wordsToBold =['reduced'];
```

contains only a single word, so matter if that get joined by `|` or `,`, it will result only in `(reduced)`, so match only that word.

Comment: Thanks, actually I saw when I add manual list of keywords in function. It is now highlighting all keywords. But when I dynamically take  list from python script it does not do. It takes text content dynamically but not the keyword list.